# Required server capabilities for a video platform?

Tags: capacity-planning

I'm a programmer and I have made a video playing platform. But I'm not sure about hardware requirements for such a system.

I think this platform will have some 10000 customer in the beginning. I do not know how to calculate but let's take these 10000 people will spend at least one hour watching videos there.

What are server requirements for such a platform or how to calculate these specifications?

Comment: i belive that your out of bandwidth until u suffer all customers at once

Comment: Well, maybe as a programmer you should start doing proper testing. Including a load test - that answers the question fast. it is not like you can not rent servers by the minute for load tests from any cloud provider.